# Find location of the first nonzero number multiple times in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I could do this iteratively with a loop but I wanted to see if anyone has an idea on how to do this outside of a for loop.

Below is a vector of numbers which has 0's and 1's. I am trying to grab the location of the first 1 in ever cluster that appears (the 1s always appear together in a bunch). Basically every time there are 1s, I only want the one where a zero comes before it.

```
    test_vector <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I'll write up a full answer, but are you familiar with `rle`? I think it might do what you need.

Comment: ah I did not know about rle, that is a nice function. Will explore using it.

Comment: There is also this very good article on R-Bloggers for further readings: http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-function-of-the-day-rle/

Comment: Thanks for the link, learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following code can work:

```
which(test_vector==1 & c(0,diff(test_vector)==1))
```

or, shorter, as mentionned in comment by @user20650:

```
which(diff(test_vector)==1) + 1
```

Both gives:

```
 #[1]   8  28  49  68  89 109 129 149 169 189 211 232 251 273 294 312 334 353 372 393 415 434 457 477 497 519 539 558 580 599
#[31] 620 639 660 680 703 722
```

you may need to modify this code in case the vector begins with a `1` and you want this position also.

*Thanks to @docendodiscimus, here is a similar option with `dplyr` package:*

```
library(dplyr)
which(test_vector != 0 & lag(test_vector == 0))
```

Comment: Another option: `library(dplyr); which(x != 0 & lag(x == 0))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks for the other option. Is `x!=0` more efficient than `x==1` (and "subsidiary" question, I'm guessing yes but is using dplyr functions more efficient ?)

Comment: I'm just using `x != 0` because OP asked for "non-zero numbers" in case there may be other values than 0 and 1. I don't think this use of dplyr::lag would speed this up, just find it quite useful and better to read than something like `c(0, diff(test_vector)==1)` (but that's personal preference)

Comment: @docendodiscimus, ok, it is indeed more practical to have a vector of same length than input. (and good point for the non-zero elements)

Answer (score 2):

EDITED TO ADD: Apologies. I wrote this up quickly and was accidentally giving you the LAST number of each run, not the first. Made some changes accordingly.

This is relatively easy to do using the command `rle` which stands for "run level encoding". Using the `rle` on your command returns an object containing two vectors, `lengths` (the length of each run) and `values` the values of the encoding.

```
run_encoding <- rle(x = test_vector)
```

What you want to know is the location of each run of 1s. To do this, we can use `cumsum` on the vector of lengths, as long as we first add 1 to the vector to be the start of vector `test_vector`.

```
run_starts <- cumsum(c(1,run_encoding$lengths))

# Here, we subset run_starts to be from the first element to the second-to-last element
run_starts <- run_starts[1:(length(run_starts)-1)]

# Next, name the elements of run_starts according to the run_encoding$values
names(run_starts) <- run_encoding$values

# Use the names() argument to get the elements of interest in run_starts
run_starts[names(run_starts) == "1"]

 1   1   1  ....
 8  28  49
```

Comment: Fascinating, thank you for the help, this is going to be a very helpful thing to know in the future.

Comment: I'm editing it because I forgot something important - but I'll have the right version up in a few. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Updated this with a corrected version (apologies for the error, was giving you a backwards answer...)

Comment: The answer above was shorter and got the job done so I will probably use that. But your post was really informative. Learned a lot about the rle function, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I think of `rle` as an unsung hero of R, so I like to share the good news of it any time I can. ;)